# Find the next number in the series

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Can you find the next number in the following series ?

2 , 0 , 3 , 5 , 25 , 119 , ?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> 721

Because

> $$2 = 0! +(-1)^0 = 1 + 1$$  $$0 = 1! + (-1)^1 = 1 - 1$$ $$3 = 2! + (-1)^2 = 2 + 1$$ $$5 = 3! + (-1)^3 = 6 - 1$$  $$25 = 4! + (-1)^4 = 24 + 1$$ $$119 = 5! + (-1)^5 = 120 - 1$$ So, $$6! + (-1)^6 = 720 + 1 = 721$$.